# How to filter a pandas dataframe based on the length of a entry

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In a pandas dataframe I have a field 'amp' that should be populated by a list of length 495.  Is there a panda-ic way to quickly filter on this length, such that all rows with field 'amp' are not equal to 495 are dropped?

I tried

```
df[len(df['amp']) == 495]
```

and this returned

```
KeyError: False
```

Comment: Please don't edit the code inside of an answer as it may conflict with the author intent and instead, comment on the answer to ask for clarification or correction if needed.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

If you specifically need `len`, then @MaxU's answer is best.

For a more general solution, you can use the [map](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) method of a Series.

```
df[df['amp'].map(len) == 495]
```

This will apply `len` to each element, which is what you want. With this method, you can use any arbitrary function, not just `len`.

Comment: can you switch the != to ==, the intent is the only keep arrays of 495.  thx

Answer (score 10):

Try this:

```
df[df['amp'].str.len() == 495]
```

Demo:

```
In [77]: df
Out[77]:
                 a
0  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
1        [1, 2, 3]
2             [-1]

In [78]: df.a.str.len()
Out[78]:
0    5
1    3
2    1
Name: a, dtype: int64

In [79]: df[df.a.str.len() == 3]
Out[79]:
                 a
1        [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Does this work even if the element is a `list`, not a `str`?

Comment: Neat.  They should probably update their documentation to indicate it can work for any type that supports `len`. From [the API](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.len.html): "Compute length of each *string* in the Series/Index.".

Comment: @SethMMorton, please feel free to create a "Pull Request" on [GitHub](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues) (just mark it as "DOC: ...") - it would be really helpful :)

Comment: Wow this is great, thanks!  @SethMMorton's answer is a bit more general (and taught me how to use map), so I chose that, but many thanks for this!

Comment: @MaxU can you switch the `!=` to `==`, the intent is the only keep arrays of 495

Comment: @DanSteingart, sure!